# How do I know when the background thread is finished with AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I take the names and phone numbers of people with string with background thread and use them somewhere. Everything works, but I want to do something. I want to show users something when this thread runs out. But I don't know how to check the condition of this thread. I'd appreciate it if you helped. Thanks in advance.

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (cursor.moveToNext()){

                    String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).trim();

                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `AsyncTask` has finished executed when `onPostExecute` is called. You should override `onPostExecute` in your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did research with the information you gave me and learned new things. I've created a test for the background thread, and I can now track all the jobs done with AsyncTask. Thanks again for great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
public class Processing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>

  ProgressDialog mProgress;
  @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(YOUR_ACTIVITIY.this);
        mProgress.setTitle("Processing");
        mProgress.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        mProgress.show();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (cursor.moveToNext()){

                    String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).trim();

                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        super.onPostExecute(v);
        mProgress.dismiss();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did research with the help of my friend and I got my answer. The solution I have reached, however, is similar to your answer. I'm choosing a valid answer to your answer. I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you mean

```
    final TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
    final Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //... your work
            uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView1.setText("finish");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But that's not the answer. We had to check this out when you were done in the background.